# intraweb access authentication via Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Hello is there any posibility to set just basic javascript authentication in Active directory to webpage in internal network so only users granted with access can view it? I heard you can just set it up in AD.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Authentication has to happen on the server. JavaScript runs in the browser (client-side), unless you're using NodeJS. So the answer to your question depends on the OS of your server, and what your server-side code is run in (NodeJS, ASP.NET, etc.).

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Thanks for answer. Well it does not necessarily need to be a javascript. I meant whatever autentication can AD offer. I am aware of various html/javascript/php ways to create such authentication but what i am looking for is just some setup in AD.. Is there such? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but how you implement it depends on which OS and web server (IIS, Apache, etc) you use. What are you using?

Comment: I will find out and update. Thanks